# Как сделать слайдер (именно изображения следующие друг за другом)

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день.
Потребовалось мне недавно слайдер изображений найти, но только очень простой.
Все что нужно было: кнопки влево/вправо и чтобы при переключении изображений, картинки не сразу переключались/затемнялись/осветвлялись, а какбы 'держались вместе' и следовали друг за другом. Вот как [здесь](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/), например. Видите? Они якобы склеены вместе при переключении.

В общем такого слайдера я не нашел, у всех слишком много наворотов.. решил написать свой. Пока что склепал это:

```
var imgNum=0;              //счетчик изображений
var separated=[тут изображения];      //массив с изображениями

$('#go_left').on('click',function(){   //просматриваем предыдущую картинку
    imgNum--;             //листаем назад счетчик
    if(imgNum<0){       //если он меньше 0
        imgNum=separated.length-1;   //идем в конец массива
    }
    $('#here').attr('src','content/'+separated[imgNum]);
});

$('#go_right').on('click',function(){   //просматриваем следующую картинку
    imgNum++;           //листаем счетчик вперед
    if(imgNum>=separated.length){     //если больше чем елементов в массиве
        imgNum=0;            //кидаем в самое начало массива
    }
    $('#here').attr('src','content/'+separated[imgNum]);
});
```

Самый простой вариант переключения изображений, такой вариант работает, но он просто переключает их, моментально.
Я же хочу получить 'еффект скольжения', где все изображения будут какбы скреплены между собой во время передвижения. Как этого добиться вообще? Может кто знает где есть примеры?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте метод [.animate()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8). Тут как бы и добавить нечего

Comment: ну я догадывался что с animate дело буду иметь, но если бы знал что именно - не писал бы сюда)  
можете в двух словах хотябы сказать как правильно будет?  
была идея грузить сразу все изображения, уже прикрепленные вряд, и при клике менять их расположение, при этом родитель прячет ненужные в данный момент изображения через hidden:overflow;   разве так и нужно?

Comment: Именно так. Если вы будете подгружать фото по очереди, то анимация у вас будет очень кривая. А так - всё загрузили и поехали карусель крутить

Comment: окей, будем пробовать)  
спасибо

Comment: хм, уважаемый тёзка, а как правильно добиться соединения самого первого и самого последнего изображения?  
  
я пока что сделал все изображения внутри LI, выстроил их горизонтально, спрятал лишнее, сделал кнопки и повесил прокрутку на них влево/вправо. но когда доходим до конца - упираемся в пустоту ) как с началом соединить?

Comment: После того, как текущее изображение скрывается за поворотом, переместите элемент в конец очереди. Это ж ясно, как Путину результаты выборов. Устали вы, батюшка )))

P.S. Сегодня уже не получится, но если до завтра не справитесь, то постараюсь помочь.

Comment: ))  
та я на сегодня тоже прекращаю, уже если честно и прокрутка слетела, влево в блок упирается и двигаться не хочет.. завтра этот слайдер по новой начну)

Answer (score 0):

игрался с каруселью, понял что строю велосипед..
поставил [этот слайдер](http://5509.github.com/jq.carousel/)